# Compute the smoothing of functions

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, probability-distributions, smoothness

Given a function $g:R^d\rightarrow R$, which is *not* necessarily continuous, I want to compute the "smoothing" of $g$, i.e.,

$G(\vec{y})=\int_{R^n} g(\vec{x}) f_{\vec{y}, \sigma}(\vec{x}) d\vec{x} $

where $f_{\mu, \sigma}(x)$ is the (multivariate) Gaussian density function.

What are the good algorithms to compute this (note that $g$ might NOT be continuous)? I assume that this is a well-studied problem, and any survey/guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but a quick Google search gives some promising links; e.g. http://elynxsdk.free.fr/ext-docs/Blur/Fast_box_blur.pdf and http://blog.ivank.net/fastest-gaussian-blur.html.